# Spring Boot application not accessible via server IP gives 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ubuntu, tomcat, digital-ocean

I have developed a webapp using spring boot. It is running as expected on my local machine's tomcat server.
Now I am trying to deploy it on Digital Ocean - ubuntu 14.04. I have installed JDK, Tomcat and have open up port 8080. The tomcat installation is successful and I can see its landing page using http://IP_ADDRESS:8080.
I am also able to login to manager app and deploy the the web application that I have developed (fmrsearch) below is the screenshot for the same
[image]

The issue is manager shows that the application is deployed and is running successfully but when I am trying to access the application using http://IP_ADDRESS:8080/fmrsearch I am getting below 404 error:
[image]

I have tried setting server.address to 0.0.0.0 and the actual IP.
server.port is set to 8080.

Ubuntu server details:
Version: 14.04
RAM: 512 MB
-Xms: 256M
-Xmx: 512M
JDK :1.7
Tomcat: 8.5.16

Comment: look for errors in `/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out` file

Comment: @VladimirL. Thanks for your reply. No such file is their on my server. I have tried looking into log files in /opt/tomcat/logs but have not found anything useful.

Comment: It maybe a firewall issue. Can you access it locally ok? You can use the linux curl utility to test urls on the command line. i.e. curl http://localhost:8080/fmrsearch, when logged on the server box

Comment: it looks like the web application is either not properly initialized during deployment or an error occurs during `index` processing (handler for application root or welcome page is not found, controllers are not properly discovered or initialized), without log file output it is hard to suggest anything. You may have reconfigured the location of application log file via Log4J, SLF4J or any other logger settings.

Comment: @Sanj I tried running curl on the server box and got following error: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

Comment: if you deploy war on external tomcat the name of the war file get set as context root. Have you tried using http://localhost:8080/<war-name>/fmrsearch

Answer (score 1):

Finally after spending almost a day I was able to figure out the issue.
Since everything related to application code was looking fine I was convinced that this is related to environment setup and I started analyzing the setup on my local and server. Thats when I realized that my local tomcat was running JDK8 and war was build using JDK8 while the server tomcat was running on JDK7.
So I uninstalled JDK7 from server and installed JDK8 thus tomcat could run on JDK8, this solved my issue and now application is running as expected.
This is strange because I was not able to found anything unusual in logs and have not read this anywhere in spring boot documentation.

So if someone is facing similar issue make sure you are running tomcat on same version of JDK on which the war is build.

Comment: For several days I have languished in agony with nowhere to turn. Was almost giving up when I saw your post. After upgrading my Tomcat's JDK from 11 to 17, my application is now accessible from the browser. Thank you man!